# How to make a line between two planes and show distance between them using tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\pgfplotsset{
    axis equal image,
    axis lines = center,
    label style={font=\tiny},
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = $y$,
    zlabel = $z$,
    xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
    yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
    zticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            xmax=3,
            zmax=3,
            zmin=-3,
            view={130}{20},
            %clip=false         <- Not working
        ]
            \addplot3[blue!60,samples=50] {3*x-4*y-8} node[below right] {\tiny $\alpha_2$};
            \addplot3[red,thick] (1+8*x,6*x,4*x) node[below right] {\tiny $L_1$};
            \addplot3[blue!60,samples=50] {3*x-4*y+2} node[below right] {\tiny $\alpha_1$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Line between planes]

I want something like this:

[image: What I want]

I was trying for a while to create the graphic on the left that fits the drawing but always the axes are longer than the three figures. How can it be fixed?

I want to add a label that indicates the distance between the planes and the line.

Also, the `x`-axis must be change with `y`-axis.

The `node labels` are not displayed, and when I try to `clip=false` then the graph dissapears.

Finally, `samples=50` for the planes are too innecesary I think (If I do not add it, they seem cut). How can we reduce compiling time?

- Line equation `L_1`: `(x,y,z) = (1,0,0) + λ(8,6,4)`
- Plane `α_1`: `3x-4y+2=0`
- Plane `α_2`: `3x-4y-8=0`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, there is a conceptual issue here. If you want to draw a plane defined by `a x + b y + c = 0`, you cannot use `\addplot3[blue!60,samples=50] {3*x-4*y+2};`. The latter will plot a function `z = a x + b y + c`. However, the plane equation above tells you that for any `x` and `y` that fulfills the equation, `z` can be arbitrary. So you need to draw the plane by finding two linearly independent vectors in it, and then e.g. by by drawing the shape that is defined by the difference of the latter. And since you seem to like animations, you may want to do that with `tikz-3dplot`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {130,140,...,480}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,declare function={
f1(\x)=(3*\x+2)/4;
f2(\x)=(3*\x-8)/4;
f3(\x)=(3*\x-2)/4;
DeltaX=2;
X1=-6/25;
X2=24/25;
X3=(X1+X2)/2;
}]
\path[use as bounding box] (-4.5,-4) rectangle (4.5,4);
%\node[below right] at (-4.5,4) {\X};
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{\X}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \draw (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[pos=1.1] {$x$};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[pos=1.1] {$y$};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[pos=1.1] {$z$};
  \ifnum\X<310
    \fill[blue,opacity=0.35] ({X2-DeltaX},{f2(X2-DeltaX)},2)
    -- ({X2-DeltaX},{f2(X2-DeltaX)},-2)
    -- ({X2+DeltaX},{f2(X2+DeltaX)},-2)
    -- ({X2+DeltaX},{f2(X2+DeltaX)},2) -- cycle;
    \draw[red,thick] ({X3+DeltaX},{(f3(X3+DeltaX)},0)
    -- ({X3-DeltaX},{(f3(X3-DeltaX)},0);
    \fill[red,opacity=0.35] ({X1-DeltaX},{f1(X1-DeltaX)},2)
    -- ({X1-DeltaX},{f1(X1-DeltaX)},-2)
    -- ({X1+DeltaX},{f1(X1+DeltaX)},-2)
    -- ({X1+DeltaX},{f1(X1+DeltaX)},2) -- cycle;
  \else
    \fill[red,opacity=0.35] ({X1-DeltaX},{f1(X1-DeltaX)},2)
    -- ({X1-DeltaX},{f1(X1-DeltaX)},-2)
    -- ({X1+DeltaX},{f1(X1+DeltaX)},-2)
    -- ({X1+DeltaX},{f1(X1+DeltaX)},2) -- cycle;
    \draw[red,thick] ({X3+DeltaX},{(f3(X3+DeltaX)},0)
    -- ({X3-DeltaX},{(f3(X3-DeltaX)},0);
    \fill[blue,opacity=0.35] ({X2-DeltaX},{f2(X2-DeltaX)},2)
    -- ({X2-DeltaX},{f2(X2-DeltaX)},-2)
    -- ({X2+DeltaX},{f2(X2+DeltaX)},-2)
    -- ({X2+DeltaX},{f2(X2+DeltaX)},2) -- cycle;
  \fi
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I never used `tikz-3dplot` package, but I will try it. Anyway, I think there is something wrong with the red line, since it must be parallel to both planes.

Comment: @manooooh Better now?